# Getting CGImage to aspect fit in Swift

Tags: ios, image, swift, image-processing, cgimage

Working on an app that takes a background image from the camera roll and then takes a PNG to overlay, manipulate the PNG (pinch, zoom, rotate, etc.), returning a composited image on the following view controller.

No matter what I try, I'm hitting a wall in figuring out how to get my code to aspect fit the background image. The overlay (topLayerImage.image) in the code below at least maintains its aspect upon conversion. The background image is being forced into a shape, though. For instance, the UIImageView is by default a vertical image for portrait view on a phone, and the resulting image comes back as that shape no matter the original aspect ratio of the original photo.

I've seen some Objective-C ways to approach this, though I've spent all afternoon with no luck. Any chance someone might know where I'm going wrong? Here's my code:

```
import UIKit

class TwoLayerViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var ghostHolderView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var bottomLayerImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var topLayerImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var amountSlider: UISlider!
    @IBOutlet weak var nextPageButton: UIButton!

    var originalPhoto: UIImage?
    var chosenGhostPhoto: UIImage?
    var newImage:UIImage?
    var newBGImage:UIImage?



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        bottomLayerImage.image = originalPhoto
        bottomLayerImage.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit

        topLayerImage.image = chosenGhostPhoto
        topLayerImage.alpha = 1.0
        topLayerImage.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit
    }

    @IBAction func handlePan(recognizer:UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        let translation = recognizer.translationInView(self.view)
        if let view = recognizer.view {
            view.center = CGPoint(x:view.center.x + translation.x,
            y:view.center.y + translation.y)
        }
        recognizer.setTranslation(CGPointZero, inView: self.view)
    }

    @IBAction func handlePinch(recognizer : UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {
        if let view = recognizer.view {
            view.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(view.transform,
                recognizer.scale, recognizer.scale)
            recognizer.scale = 1
        }
    }

    @IBAction func handleRotate(recognizer : UIRotationGestureRecognizer) {
        if let view = recognizer.view {
            view.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(view.transform, recognizer.rotation)
            var transform:CGAffineTransform = view.transform
            var angle:CGFloat = atan2(transform.b, transform.a)
            println(angle)
        }
    }

    @IBAction func sliderChangeAmount(sender: UISlider) {

        //        let sliderValue = CGFloat(sender.value)
        //
        //        topLayerImage.alpha = sliderValue

    }


    @IBAction func combineImagesButton(sender: AnyObject) {

        let originalWidth = originalPhoto!.size.width
        let originalHeight = originalPhoto!.size.height
        let finalWidth = bottomLayerImage.frame.size.width
        let finalHeight = bottomLayerImage.frame.size.height
        let finalSize : CGSize = CGSizeMake(finalWidth, finalHeight)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(finalSize)

        let size = CGSizeApplyAffineTransform(originalPhoto!.size, CGAffineTransformMakeScale(finalWidth/originalWidth, finalHeight/originalHeight))

        originalPhoto!.drawInRect(CGRect(origin: CGPointZero, size: size))


        // originalPhoto!.drawInRect(bottomLayerImage.frame)

        let imgCon = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        CGContextTranslateCTM( imgCon, 0.5 * finalSize.width, 0.5 * finalSize.height ) ;
        CGContextRotateCTM( imgCon, atan2(topLayerImage.transform.b, topLayerImage.transform.a));

        chosenGhostPhoto!.drawInRect(topLayerImage.frame, blendMode: kCGBlendModeNormal, alpha:0.8)

        newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()

        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        println(newImage)
        println(finalSize)
        println(originalPhoto!.size.width, originalPhoto!.size.height)
    }

    func getBoundingRectAfterRotation(rect: CGRect, angle: Float) -> CGRect {
        let newWidth : Float = Float(rect.size.width) * abs(cosf(angle)) + Float(rect.size.height) * fabs(sinf(angle))

        let newHeight : Float = Float(rect.size.height) * fabs(cosf(angle)) + Float(rect.size.width) * fabs(sinf(angle))

        let newX : Float = Float(rect.origin.x) + ((Float(rect.size.width) - newWidth) / 2);
        let newY : Float = Float(rect.origin.y) + ((Float(rect.size.height) - newHeight) / 2);
        let rotatedRect : CGRect = CGRectMake(CGFloat(newX), CGFloat(newY), CGFloat(newWidth), CGFloat(newHeight))
        return rotatedRect
    }


    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if let vc = segue.destinationViewController as? CombinedLayerViewController {

            vc.fullImage = self.newImage
        }
    }

}
```

UPDATE: Timothy's suggestion, with some minor tweaks, worked on the background issue, but I'm having trouble with the overlay, apparently in the scale and, I think, origin point. Here's my sloppy code:

```
import UIKit

class TwoLayerViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var ghostHolderView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var bottomLayerImage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var topLayerImage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var amountSlider: UISlider!
@IBOutlet weak var nextPageButton: UIButton!

var originalPhoto: UIImage?
var chosenGhostPhoto: UIImage?
var newImage:UIImage?
var newBGImage:UIImage?



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    bottomLayerImage.image = originalPhoto
    bottomLayerImage.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit

    topLayerImage.image = chosenGhostPhoto
//        topLayerImage.alpha = 1.0
//        topLayerImage.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit

}

@IBAction func handlePan(recognizer:UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    let translation = recognizer.translationInView(self.view)
    if let view = recognizer.view {
        view.center = CGPoint(x:view.center.x + translation.x,
            y:view.center.y + translation.y)
    }
    recognizer.setTranslation(CGPointZero, inView: self.view)

}

@IBAction func handlePinch(recognizer : UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {
    if let view = recognizer.view {
        view.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(view.transform,
            recognizer.scale, recognizer.scale)
        recognizer.scale = 1

    }
}

@IBAction func handleRotate(recognizer : UIRotationGestureRecognizer) {
    if let view = recognizer.view {
        view.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(view.transform, recognizer.rotation)
        var transform:CGAffineTransform = view.transform
        var angle:CGFloat = atan2(transform.b, transform.a)
        println(angle)

    }
}

@IBAction func sliderChangeAmount(sender: UISlider) {

    //        let sliderValue = CGFloat(sender.value)
    //
    //        topLayerImage.alpha = sliderValue

}


@IBAction func combineImagesButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    var originalPhotoFrame: CGRect?
    var backgroundLayerFrame: CGRect?
    var ghostOriginalPhotoFrame: CGRect?
    var ghostBackgroundLayerFrame: CGRect?

    if bottomLayerImage.image!.size.width > bottomLayerImage.image!.size.height {

        originalPhotoFrame = CGRect(x: 0,y: 0, width: bottomLayerImage.image!.size.width, height: bottomLayerImage.image!.size.height)
        backgroundLayerFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: bottomLayerImage.frame.size.width, height: bottomLayerImage.frame.size.height)

    } else {

        originalPhotoFrame = CGRect(x: 0,y: 0, width: bottomLayerImage.frame.size.width, height: bottomLayerImage.frame.height)
        backgroundLayerFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: bottomLayerImage.frame.size.width, height: bottomLayerImage.frame.size.height)
    }

    // Now figure out whether the ScaleAspectFit was horizontally or vertically bound.
    let horizScale = backgroundLayerFrame!.width / originalPhotoFrame!.width
    let vertScale = backgroundLayerFrame!.height / originalPhotoFrame!.height
    let myScale = min(horizScale, vertScale)

    // So we don't need to do each of these calculations on a separate line, but for ease of explanation…
    // Now we can calculate the size to scale originalPhoto
    let scaledSize = CGSize(width: originalPhotoFrame!.size.width * myScale,
        height: originalPhotoFrame!.size.height * myScale)
    // And now we need to center originalPhoto inside backgroundLayerFrame
    let scaledOrigin = CGPoint(x: (backgroundLayerFrame!.width - scaledSize.width) / 2,
        y: (backgroundLayerFrame!.height - scaledSize.height) / 2)

    // Put it all together
    let scaledPhotoRect = CGRect(origin: scaledOrigin, size: scaledSize)


    //////

    if topLayerImage.image!.size.width > topLayerImage.image!.size.height {

        ghostOriginalPhotoFrame = CGRect(x: 0,y: 0, width: topLayerImage.image!.size.width, height: topLayerImage.image!.size.height)
        ghostBackgroundLayerFrame = CGRect(x: topLayerImage.frame.origin.x, y: topLayerImage.frame.origin.y, width: topLayerImage.frame.size.width, height: topLayerImage.frame.size.height)

    } else {

        ghostOriginalPhotoFrame = CGRect(x: topLayerImage.frame.origin.x,y: topLayerImage.frame.origin.y, width: topLayerImage.frame.size.width, height: topLayerImage.frame.height)
        ghostBackgroundLayerFrame = CGRect(x: topLayerImage.frame.origin.x, y: topLayerImage.frame.origin.y, width: topLayerImage.frame.size.width, height: topLayerImage.frame.size.height)
    }

    // Now figure out whether the ScaleAspectFit was horizontally or vertically bound.
    let ghostHorizScale = ghostBackgroundLayerFrame!.width / ghostOriginalPhotoFrame!.width
    let ghostVertScale = ghostBackgroundLayerFrame!.height / ghostOriginalPhotoFrame!.height
    let ghostMyScale = min(ghostHorizScale, ghostVertScale)

    // So we don't need to do each of these calculations on a separate line, but for ease of explanation…
    // Now we can calculate the size to scale originalPhoto
    let ghostScaledSize = CGSize(width: ghostOriginalPhotoFrame!.size.width * ghostMyScale,
        height: ghostOriginalPhotoFrame!.size.height * ghostMyScale)
    // And now we need to center originalPhoto inside backgroundLayerFrame
    let ghostScaledOrigin = CGPoint(x: (ghostBackgroundLayerFrame!.width - ghostScaledSize.width) / 2,
        y: (ghostBackgroundLayerFrame!.height - ghostScaledSize.height) / 2)

    // Put it all together
    let ghostScaledPhotoRect = CGRect(origin: ghostScaledOrigin, size: ghostScaledSize)



    //////






//        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(scaledSize)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(scaledSize, false, 0)

    originalPhoto!.drawInRect(CGRect(origin: CGPointZero, size: scaledSize))


    let imgCon = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
//        CGContextTranslateCTM( imgCon, 0.5 * finalSize.width, 0.5 * finalSize.height ) ;
    CGContextRotateCTM( imgCon, atan2(topLayerImage.transform.b, topLayerImage.transform.a));

//        chosenGhostPhoto!.drawInRect(CGRect(origin: topLayerImage.frame.origin, size: ghostScaledSize))

    chosenGhostPhoto!.drawInRect(ghostScaledPhotoRect, blendMode: kCGBlendModeNormal, alpha: 0.8)

//        chosenGhostPhoto!.drawInRect(CGRect(origin: chosenGhostPhoto, size: ghostScaledSize), blendMode: kCGBlendModeNormal, alpha:0.8)



    newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    println(newImage)
//        println(finalSize)
    println(originalPhoto!.size.width, originalPhoto!.size.height)

}

//    func getBoundingRectAfterRotation(rect: CGRect, angle: Float) -> CGRect {
//        let newWidth : Float = Float(rect.size.width) * abs(cosf(angle)) + Float(rect.size.height) * fabs(sinf(angle))
//        
//        let newHeight : Float = Float(rect.size.height) * fabs(cosf(angle)) + Float(rect.size.width) * fabs(sinf(angle))
//        
//        let newX : Float = Float(rect.origin.x) + ((Float(rect.size.width) - newWidth) / 2);
//        let newY : Float = Float(rect.origin.y) + ((Float(rect.size.height) - newHeight) / 2);
//        let rotatedRect : CGRect = CGRectMake(CGFloat(newX), CGFloat(newY), CGFloat(newWidth), CGFloat(newHeight))
//        return rotatedRect
//    }


override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if let vc = segue.destinationViewController as? CombinedLayerViewController {

        vc.fullImage = self.newImage
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The screenshots make it a lot clearer. That first screen shot shows exactly what `ScaleAspectFit` does: the landscape image is scaled without distortion to fill the entire narrower width of `bottomLayerImage` and centered vertically in the larger height. However: *nothing changes `bottomLayerImage.frame` in this code*. One thing that would make this easier to visualize would be to set `bottomLayerImage.backgroundColor = .greenColor()` so you can see that bottomLayerImage is taking up the same amount of screen space and simply centering `originalPhoto` vertically.

The transforms set on the parent view in `handlePinch` and `handleRotate` will adjust `bottomLayerImage.frame` since that's stored in superview's coordinates, but the work of `ScaleAspectFit` isn't applied to the frame.

That means in `combineImagesButton` the math that calculates `size` is wrong and when you draw `originalPhoto` in the rect it distorts. To get the effect you're looking for you need to calculate the scale that was applied by `ScaleAspectFit`. I whipped up a playground to show the math. Could be optimized and whatnot, but should convey the gist of what you need.

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import UIKit

// Just some test values. Adjust them to see different results
let originalPhotoFrame = CGRect(x: 0,y: 0, width: 3000, height: 2000)
let backgroundLayerFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 640, height: 960)

// Now figure out whether the ScaleAspectFit was horizontally or vertically bound.
let horizScale = backgroundLayerFrame.width / originalPhotoFrame.width
let vertScale = backgroundLayerFrame.height / originalPhotoFrame.height
let myScale = min(horizScale, vertScale)

// So we don't need to do each of these calculations on a separate line, but for ease of explanation…
// Now we can calculate the size to scale originalPhoto
let scaledSize = CGSize(width: originalPhotoFrame.size.width * myScale,
 height: originalPhotoFrame.size.height * myScale)
// And now we need to center originalPhoto inside backgroundLayerFrame
let scaledOrigin = CGPoint(x: (backgroundLayerFrame.width - scaledSize.width) / 2,
 y: (backgroundLayerFrame.height - scaledSize.height) / 2)

// Put it all together
let scaledPhotoRect = CGRect(origin: scaledOrigin, size: scaledSize)
```

You're going to want to do the same thing with `chosenGhostPhoto` and `topLayerImage` and combine that with the math you're already doing for the ghost but that should be pretty straightforward with this example.

**UPDATE 2015-06-03**

OK, I finally had a chance to look at your updated code. A few things stick out.

1. Just to confirm: the three gesture recognizers all have topLayerImage set as `recognizer.view` correct? So they are only adjusting the ghost?
2. You commented out `topLayerImage.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit` which means the ghost will get stretched if it has a different aspect ratio than `topLayerImage`. I suspect you want that uncommented.
3. In my playground `originalPhotoFrame` & `backgroundLayerFrame` were set up simply because I didn't have all of your code to work with and were intended to be test/sample data. I'm not sure why you're doing what you're doing in `combineImagesButton` where you're looking at whether the image is wider than it is tall but I think it's wrong. Instead of `originalPhotoFrame.[width|height]` you can use `originalPhoto.size.[width|height]` and instead of `backgroundLayerFrame` you can use `bottomLayerImage.frame` when you calculate `myScale`.
4. The calculations in my playground for `scaledSize` and `scaledOrigin` were simply to replicate what `bottomLayerImage` is doing because of the `.ScaleAspectFit`: it stretches the image as much as it can without distortion and then it centers the scaled image in the frame. Replicating that for the ghost doesn't work because the recognizers adjust `topLayerImage.transform` which means you can't use `topLayerImage.frame` (as per the warning in the `UIView` documentation for the `transform` property.) My first thought here is to cache the original `topLayerImage.frame` in `viewDidLoad` and just use the original value in the final math but see #6 below about a rotation caveat.
5. You don't need `scaledOrigin` if you're creating the context to be `scaledSize` and drawing at origin like you are. `scaledOrigin` was only to calculate `scaledPhotoRect` which you aren't using (so lose it as well).
6. Are you handling device rotation? If the user rotates from portrait to landscape you need to adjust for that in any ghost math. If you aren't doing rotation I'd suggest caching `topLayerImage.frame` in `viewDidLoad`, but be aware you'll have to update that if you support landscape orientation. I'm not sure what happens when you rotate the device and your view has a non-identity transform applied and I think the answer is different for different versions of iOS. Offhand I think you're going to need to stash your transform away, set it back to identity, and then read out the frame again but that's going to cause a visual pop. Maybe you could get away with doing that, calling `layoutSubviews`, getting your value, putting the transform back, and call `layoutSubviews` again, so that it all happens without an intervening render but I'm not certain. Anyway, just be aware you need to test about what happens during a rotation.

**What to do about the ghost**

- You have two different transforms you need to apply. The first is the replication of what `.ScaleAspectFit` did for you in the first place and the second is the combined changes the user made using the gesture recognizers.
- If you change the code for `ghostScaledSize` the same way I list above for the `scaledSize` but use the cached `topLayerImage.frame` value and then just call `chosenGhostPhoto!.drawInRect(CGRect(origin: CGPointZero, size: scaledSize))` you should get a ghost, at the original image size, in the top left corner of the final image. I'd do that and confirm it works.
- Once you've gotten this far things are in pretty good shape. Now you can just take the `bottomLayerImage.transform` and apply it to the context using `CGContextConcatCTM` before drawing the ghost image. (Or possibly you need to take the *inverse* of the transform? I'm not sure and it should be obvious in testing.) It's important to do this as a single operation because if you separately apply the rotation & the translation as you're trying to do you have to do them in the same order as iOS. Plus at this point, you've already got the transform so there's no reason to decompose it and then apply each operation separately. You want to apply both parts anyway.

Comment: Sure, below are some screenshots. In the first, you can see how someone might adjust the topLayerImage (the ghost) and the bottomLayerImage is just one chosen from the camera roll.

The second image is the result. The third is a repositioned ghost photo so you can see it better. It appears the aspect ratio of that image stays, which can't be said of the background image.

http://imgur.com/7ymXJG7,6OJdwVW,jD9byza
http://imgur.com/7ymXJG7,6OJdwVW,jD9byza#1
http://imgur.com/7ymXJG7,6OJdwVW,jD9byza#2

Comment: After looking more closely, I stand corrected: The ghost image does appear to distort some.

Comment: @Chris does the code in my edited answer help you with your issue? If so, could you accept the answer and if not, can you tell me more about the continuing difficulty?

Comment: I was just trying it out tonight. Seemed to solve the background issue, but I can't seem to understand how to apply this to the ghost properly. I'll update the above code and post some screenshots. I'll paste my updated code above (forgive that I haven't cleaned it up much). These are in order of what you'd see before/after: http://imgur.com/fP5ATEv,ppHfE6v,2aNkZ0r,NKaDfOt,Z9Chefg,0UxZs7G#0

Comment: Timothy, any thoughts on the update I posted? I'm obviously in over my head on how to apply it.

Comment: Yeah sorry, the last couple of weeks got crazy busy and I haven't had a chance to take a look yet. Hopefully I'll be able to spend some time on it tomorrow.

Comment: Timothy, any chance you might share your thoughts on how to apply this to the top level? I've been reading away and posting this on any Swift board I can find and no one else has even taken a crack at it. You could make a killing making a tutorial on this because apparently no one else is willing to share the info on this technique.

Comment: @Chris Did you see my edit on June 3rd? I'm concerned about device rotation, but ignoring that for now I think if you work through the stuff below the UPDATE 2015-06-03 line you should be in good shape. Short version: once you set the transform on a view to non-identity you can no longer use the `frame` property of that view, which is the bulk of your ghost problem. Work through 1-5 in my list above, then cache the value of `topLayerImage.frame` in `viewDidLoad` and use that as I list in the first two bullet points under "What to do about the ghost" and you should have a non-distorted ghost.

Comment: Once you have the ghost properly in the composite image you just need the transforms from the gesture recognizers. The third bullet point under "What to do about the ghost" should cover I think. The key bit is not decompose the transform, just grab the whole thing and apply it all at once.

Comment: Oh! I didn't even see that. Thanks, Timothy, I'll try this out and report back. Can't thank you enough for your insight.

Comment: I have a couple questions: First, what do you mean cache that value? Just set it before I get to the math? And I think I followed your other edits but still am not quite sure what you mean when you say, "If you change the code for ghostScaledSize the same way I list above for the scaledSize..." I commented out the ghostScaledOrigin and ghostScaledPhotoRect, but then it draws it out of proportion. It does seem to want to draw it all based off the top-right corner so far, at least.

Comment: @Chris: In `combineImagesButton` you can't use `topLayerImage.frame` because you can't use the frame of UIView that has a non-identity transform set. (See the warning in the UIView documentation for transform.) So in `viewDidLoad`, before the recognizers do anything save `topLayerImage.frame` into a ivar and use it anywhere you want to access `topLayerImage.frame` later. That's what I mean by cache the value. And it's probably what is causing the remaining distortion.